# How to move multiple list attachments using REST batching in SharePoint Online

Tags: rest, sharepoint, odata, sharepoint-online

I need to copy list large number of items with attachments from one list to another. For same I have written REST batching. I could not find any documentation on how to move attachments using REST batching.

Has anyone tried moving attachments using batching? What changes shall I make to regular batching code to move attachments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST batching supports only CRUD operations hence attachment movement is not possible. I implemented PS (with PnP) to move attachments. If anyone needs any help, please let me know in comments.